# sudo xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1976x1080_60.00 X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr

When I try to change resolution this comes:

```
$ sudo xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1976x1080_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  32
  Current serial number in output stream:  33
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't how you went about it but these are the steps I found that should be used:

1. Use xrandr to make sure that the new mode can fit within the maximum framebuffer size:

   ```
   xrandr | grep maximum
   ```
2. Use gtf to create a mode line:

   ```
   gtf 1440 900 59.9
   ```

   - Output would look like this:

     ```
     # 1440x900 @ 59.90 Hz (GTF) hsync: 55.83 kHz; pclk: 106.29 MHz
     Modeline "1440x900_59.90"  106.29  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync
     ```
3. Add new mode from `step 2` using xrandr

   ```
   xrandr --newmode "1440x900_59.90"  106.29  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync
   ```
4. Add this newly added mode to the desired output (VGA/LVDS etc):

   ```
   xrandr --addmode VGA 1440x900_59.90
   ```
5. Choose the new mode:

   ```
   xrandr --output VGA --mode 1440x900_59.90
   ```

Note:

Change these `1440x900_59.90` numbers to `1976x1080_60.00` based on your query.

Source:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1112186

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding%20undetected%20resolutions

Comment: Those are the steps that create the error when doing the "--addmode" step.