# Dual monitor setup issue, one monitor works but the other has poor resolution, Nvidia GT710 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I installed Ubuntu to learn more about Linux and I want to use it for coding and every day. I installed the latest version on my computer alongside Windows 8.1 (dual boot).

My device has Nvidia GT710 as GPU.

I have two monitors:

1. Acer 18.5 monitor
2. Samsung 21.1 monitor

The monitors have different resolutions:

1. Acer monitor has 1366x768 and
2. Samsung monitor has 1920x1080

When I installed Ubuntu I found the driver that came with it did not support the Acer monitor well. It only showed 1080x700 I guess, not sure, but it was horrible to look at.

I looked for drivers on the Nvidia site, downloaded, removed default Ubuntu driver and installed that one, and surprisingly (to me), the resulting display was even worse; now it shows black stripes and way smaller resolution.

Ubuntu detects it as "unknown monitor", but detects the Samsung fine, and has no issues with the Samsung monitor.

Things I've tried so far:

1. Commands I looked up to fix
2. Commands to remove default Ubuntu driver
3. Installed Nvidia driver from official Nvidia site
4. Commands to add custom resolution to add it to the monitor

Here are more details for what I tried and I have.
Here what I have, after installing the Nvidia driver:
https://ibb.co/kxv8c9
https://ibb.co/hknMx9
https://ibb.co/gkbEH9

I had downloaded the driver from https://www.nvidia.in/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-in

And from there I got a .run file, which is NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.87.run, I believe this is the latest driver from Nvidia.

When I tried to install first time, Nvidia driver showed up saying a driver already installed and asked me to disable it, I'm sorry I forgot the name of the default Ubuntu display driver, the name started with an N.

So I searched on Google how to uninstall it, and I did it by commands, and then

I installed Nvidia driver by commands I wrote below:

```
sudo chmod +x some-app.run
sudo ./some-app.run
```

and as I said before, it worsens the resolution even more after computer restart,
and I tried this after it to add custom resolution,

```
xrandr
cvt 1600 900
sudo xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-0 "1600x900_60.00"
```

I tried again just now and this is what it shows to me
https://ibb.co/cAutc9

Tried again some commands with xrandr and here what happens,

```
tony@tony-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo cvt 1280 800 60
# 1280x800 59.81 Hz (CVT 1.02MA) hsync: 49.70 kHz; pclk: 83.50 MHz
Modeline "1280x800_60.00"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync
tony@tony-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x800_60.00"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync
tony@tony-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2880 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected 960x540+0+246 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   960x540       59.82*+
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   480x270       59.82  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+960+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
  1440x900_60.00 (0x2bd) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1528 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1366x768 (0x2c4) 85.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1366 start 1494 end 1624 total 1798 skew    0 clock  47.55KHz
        v: height  768 start  770 end  776 total  795           clock  59.81Hz
  1368x768_85.50 (0x2cc) 126.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1456 end 1600 total 1832 skew    0 clock  69.05KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  810           clock  85.25Hz
  1280x720_60.00 (0x2e5) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1280x1024_60.00 (0x2e9) 108.880MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  63.60KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1060           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x800_60.00 (0x2f1) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
tony@tony-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo xrandr -addmode VGA-0 1280x800_60.00
xrandr: unrecognized option '-addmode'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
tony@tony-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x800_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
tony@tony-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$
```

Tried this [sudo xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1976x1080_60.00 X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964796/sudo-xrandr-addmode-lvds1-1976x1080-60-00-x-error-of-failed-request-badmatch) just now, doesn't work.

I tried multiple times changing numbers, but didn't work.

Since yesterday I'm trying to put EDID data for my monitor, I had found even windows has "BAD_EDID" in its registry so what I think is, something is wrong by using DVI to VGA adapter, however in windows the monitor works fine even with showing bad edid data in registry.

I will keep updating this, someone can get help by reading this.

Nothing worked so far. What else can I try?

**Reinstalled Ubuntu and this time I kept the driver it came with and did not install Nvidia driver, tried xrandr commands and it works fine now, took 2 days to find out.**